# My divs are not aligned when text overflows (but only sometimes)

Tags: html, css

I'd like to show the container in the best way for any resolution, not too wide and not too thin:

- 1 blocks/row on resolutions up to 640x480;
- 2 blocks/row on 1024x768 resolution;
- 3 blocks/row for 1366x768 and up;
- 4 blocks for resolutions 1680x1050 and over.

Ideally, it would resize the container to the current screen width.

The `<div class="L">` is in a loop, and will show 5-100 times; `<div ID="A">` has no styles.

```
<div id="A">
...
    <div class="L V">
        <a href="#"><img src="thumb.jpg">
        <h2>short title</h2>
        medium to long description about lorem ipsum (10-500chrs)
        </a>
    </div>
...
</div>
```

`<div class="L">` is used in some other places also; `<div class="V">` is used mostly for this view:

```
div.L {
    border:1px;
    padding:3px;
    margin:2px;
    font-size:21px;
    text-align:justify;
}
div.V {
    width:486px;
    height:149px;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
div.L img {
    float:left;
    min-width:80px;
    min-height:80px;
    padding-right:4px;
}
div.V img {
    max-width:157px;
    max-height:118px;
}
div.L h2 {
    margin:1px;
    font-size:21px;
}
div.V h2 {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

**The Problem:**
My guess is that it may have something to do with the variable text, because they are all aligned nicely when there's no description (fixed size), or when there are just a couple words.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qvpuX/1/

Comment: jsfiddle ! jsfiddle ! jsfiddle ! please

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VYZja/3/embedded/result/ example when not aligned @badZoke

Comment: are you looking at something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/VYZja/4/embedded/result/

Comment: you want this to be responsive?

Comment: I've updated my answer please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `div.V` css to the following,

```
div.V { 
    width:416px; 
    height:149px; 
    float:left; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

[Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/VYZja/4/embedded/result/)

**EDIT:**

You can add variable width to your `div` as follows,

```
@media all and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 600px){
    div.V{
        width: 416px;
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 320px){
    div.V{
        width: 100px;
    }

}
```

**NOTE:** I've added `width: 100px;` just as a reference to show that it works, you can add what `width` you want (`300px`, I'm guessing from your comment)

[**Test Link - Responsive**](http://jsfiddle.net/VYZja/6/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `float: left` rule to the `div.V` selector

http://codepen.io/timothyasp/pen/AFerh

Full View: http://codepen.io/timothyasp/full/AFerh